# ACF Pill Identifier MySQL code not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to build Pill Identifier project using WordPress and ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

I have HTML Form with jQuery as bellow:

[HTML Form][1]

In MySQL Database, data are shown as bellow:
When I use the following query:

```
select * from wp_postmeta where (meta_key = "dd_pill_shape" and meta_value="round" ) or (meta_key= "dd_med_color" and meta_value="yellow") or (meta_key="dd_pill_code" and meta_value="code333")
```

[Data from MySQL][2]

What I am trying to reach is When someone enter data in HTML Form to get only relative medicines (Decided by `post_id`)

I am now stuck that it shows wrong result. as bellow:

[Wrong result][3]

This is the code I am using now in my PHP file; but it also not giving the intended result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,post_title
FROM wp_posts as t1 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.post_id 
WHERE (t1.post_type = "post" 
and t1.post_status="publish")
AND ( 
    
    (t2.meta_key = "dd_pill_code" and t2.meta_value = "'. urldecode($drugcode) . '")
xor  ( t2.meta_key="dd_med_color" and t2.meta_value = "'. urldecode($drugcolor) . '")
 xor (t2.meta_key="dd_pill_shape" and t2.meta_value = "'. urldecode($drugshape) . '")
    )
```

Thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGCMU.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5nwI.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwT6L.png

Comment: Why are you writing your own database queries here to begin with, instead of using WP functionality to select & filter posts?

Comment: @04FS Its a custom project where I need to use external PHP file and not WP Query